# How to prevent automatic connection to WiFi

Tags: java, android, android-networking

I try to prevent automatic connection to WiFi and displaying dialog box after turning on WiFi adapter from notification bar.

I register programmatically BroadcastReceiver that receives WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION. In WIFI_STATE_ENABLED I remove network from the configured network list. But it does not work.

I register BroadcastReceiver in:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    registerReceiver(wifiStatusReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION));
}
```

And unregister in onStop method.

BroadcastReceiver code:

```
public class WiFiStatusReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private WifiManager wifiManager;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    if(!isInitialStickyBroadcast()) { //it is not a sticky intent

        switch(wifiManager.getWifiState()) {

            case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING:
                    Toast.makeText(context, R.string.enabling_wifi, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

            case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED:
                    Toast.makeText(context, R.string.enabled_wifi, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    wifiManager.disconnect();

                    if(!wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks().isEmpty()) { //there are some networks

                        for(WifiConfiguration wifiConfig :wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks()) {
                            wifiManager.removeNetwork(wifiConfig.networkId); 
                        }
                    }

                break;

            case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLING:
                    Toast.makeText(context, R.string.disabling_wifi, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                break;

            case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED:
                    Toast.makeText(context, R.string.disabled_wifi, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                break;
        }
    } else { //is a sticky intent

        wifiManager.disconnect();

        if(!wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks().isEmpty()) { //there are some networks

            for(WifiConfiguration wifiConfig :wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks()) {
                wifiManager.removeNetwork(wifiConfig.networkId); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to **Disable the Wifi**............. and **when needed enable it**.........

```
boolean isOn = false;
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)this.context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(isOn);
```

Comment: And what if we would like to use WiFi, without connection to any device ?

Comment: Ok but when I trun on WiFi programmatically the dialog box with the avaliable networks apperas.

Comment: @Vash...What do you mean by without connection to any device.... ?? then what is wifi for.......?? Usually wifi is used in ad-hoc or infrastructure mode, i have not yet been able to create a ad-hoc network with my HTC explorer, but yes infrastructure mode is working...

Comment: @ghost did you put my code in your program and tried it out...i am sure it will get off..and moreover you can manually check it out..

Comment: where should i put your your code in broadcast ? i want to inform user about state of wifi but prevent automatic connection.

Comment: I dont think your phone will automatically connect to the wifi router, until you mention one....